# Agora video recording: File recording being display only background. Not video and audio

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, agora-web-sdk-ng, agora-cloud-recording

We create online events and use agora to communicate ( agora rtc ).
But when recording the event with agora, it only shows the background in video record
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8k0L.png)

All steps to create channel by agora SDK web:

1. I create **rtc token**  ( ruby on rails `gem agora_dynamic_key` )

```
{
 app_id: @app_id,
 app_certificate: ENV['AGORA_CERTIFICATE'],
 channel_name: @channel_name,
 uid: 0,
 role: AgoraDynamicKey::RTCTokenBuilder::Role::PUBLISHER,
 privilege_expired_ts: EXPIRATION_TIME_IN_SECONDS
}
```

2. All my client join channel agora

```
agoraEngine.join(appId, channel, token, uid)
```

3. I check list users in the channel by `"https://api.agora.io/dev/v1/channel/user/#{@app_id}/#{@channel_name}"`
   This return two uses ids ( 45, 201 )
4. acquire_recording    ( mode **mix** )

```
body: {
        cname: @channel_name,
        uid: "45",
        clientRequest: {
          region: 'AP',
          resourceExpiredHour: 24,
          scene: 0,
        }
      }
```

5. start_recording

```
{
        cname: @channel_name,
        uid: "45",
        clientRequest: {
          token: signature,
          recordingConfig: {
            maxIdleTime: 30,
            streamTypes: 2,
            audioProfile: 1,
            channelType: 0, 
            videoStreamType: 0,
            transcodingConfig: {
              width: 640,
              height: 360,
              fps: 15,
              bitrate: 400,
              mixedVideoLayout: 1,
              backgroundColor: "#FF0000",
            },
            subscribeVideoUids: [
              "45", "201"
            ],
            subscribeAudioUids: [
              "45", "201"
            ],
            subscribeUidGroup: 0
          },
          recordingFileConfig: {
            avFileType: [
              "hls",
              "mp4"
            ],
          },
          storageConfig: {
            vendor: AMAZON_S3,
            region: AP_SOUTHEAST_1,
            bucket: ENV['BUCKET_NAME'],
            accessKey: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
            secretKey: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
            fileNamePrefix: ["agoraRecording", "eventId#{@event.id}"],
          }
        },
      }
```

6. Stop recording

```
{
        cname: @channel_name,
        uid: "45",
        clientRequest: {
          async_stop: false,
        }
      }
```

When all steps are success
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L71O3.png)
Open file `.m3u8` by `VLC media player`
Just display like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEdAQ.png)
Only background, no video, no audio
Even though user 45 shared the screen and mic